# Protractor error --- TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I am new to protractor testing of angularjs. 
Basically I want to check a checkbox if it is unchecked. With the following code I get the error as in title "TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"

```
var PageObject = function () {
    this.hidePanelHeaderCb = element(by.id("hidePanelHeader"));

    this.checkHidePanelHeaderCb = function() {
        this.hidePanelHeaderCb.isSelected().then(function (selected) {
          if(selected !== true) {
                (this.hidePanelHeaderCb).click();
          }
        });
    };
};
module.exports = PageObject;
```

the webpage snippet which I got with right click -> inspect is:

```
<span id="hidePanelHeader" ng-class="{'icon-CheckBoxSelected': panelProperties.hidePanelHeader, 'icon-CheckBoxUnselected': !panelProperties.hidePanelHeader}" ng-click="switchHidePanelHeader()" role="button" tabindex="0" class="icon-CheckBoxSelected" style=""></span>
```

I tried using isChecked() and it gives a different error.

I called using  panelPropertiesPageObject.checkHidePanelHeaderCb();

All the other functions using this manner of code are working fine. Its the checkbox code that I added which is not working. So using "document" instead of "this" is probably not the reason.

Comment: It seems like You are not getting the DOM element correctly. Try find element by document.getElementById("hidePanelHeader")

Comment: @SandeepSharma The click is quite deep, it's more like Konstantin's answer, that the `this` context is no longer the one he expects

Comment: Yes, here this is also binded to calling context :- not binded to outer global this..

Comment: @divya, as your question is very *protractor-specific*, probably you want to mention protractor in the title. At least for me this would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, Ice, Konstantin for your replies. I modified the title and the code snippet to accurately show whats in the program. All the other functions using this manner of code are working fine. Its the checkbox code that I added which is not working. So using "document" instead of "this" is probably not the reason.

Comment: @Divya But there still is `(this.hidePanelHeaderCb).click();` in the example. See answer below;

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with JavaScript **scopes**. In functions, `this` refers to the function object. So with every `this.hidePanelHeaderCb` statement in a function, you add a property to this object.

Instead you can store the element promise in a variable and work with it.

Please try this:

```
var PageObject = function () {

    this.checkHidePanelHeaderCb = function() {
        var hidePanelHeader = element(by.id("hidePanelHeader"));
        hidePanelHeader.isSelected().then(function (selected) {
            if(selected !== true) {
                hidePanelHeader.click();
            }
        });
    };

};

module.exports = PageObject;
```

This is all I can tell you about the syntax. More is hard to add without HTML and more JS context.

---

**Edit:** The example above uses three `hidePanelHeaderCb` properties on different objects:

```
var PageObject = function () {
    // #1 PageObject.hidePanelHeaderCb (defined here)
    this.hidePanelHeaderCb = element(by.id("hidePanelHeader"));

    // PageObject.checkHidePanelHeaderCb (defined here)
    this.checkHidePanelHeaderCb = function() {
        // #2 PageObject.checkHidePanelHeaderCb.hidePanelHeaderCb (undefined)
        this.hidePanelHeaderCb.isSelected().then(function (selected) {
          if(selected !== true) {
                // #3 anonymousThenCallback.hidePanelHeaderCb (also undefined)
                (this.hidePanelHeaderCb).click();
          }
        });
    };
};
module.exports = PageObject;
```

Comment: I have added more information to my question as your previous answer was based on absence of that information.

Comment: No. `(this.hidePanelHeaderCb).click();` still references a `hidePanelHeaderCb`on object `function (selected) { ...}`. That is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your time Konstantin. I had not been able to understand why the other code which used "this" in the same way worked. But now a colleague told me its because of the promise that the this object is not visible inside the promise. Due to some closure the way it works is ... this.checkHidePanelHeaderCb = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.hidePanelHeaderCb.isSelected().then(function(selected) {
      if(selected !== true) {
            that.hidePanelHeaderCb.click();
      }
    });
};

Answer (score 0):

Following works using closure for obviating the issue caused by the promise:

```
this.checkHidePanelHeaderCb = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.hidePanelHeaderCb.isSelected().then(function(selected) {
      if(selected !== true) {
            that.hidePanelHeaderCb.click();
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using ES2015 (ES6):**

If you are using ES2015 (ES6), this could be fixed with:

```
var PageObject = function () {
  this.hidePanelHeaderCb = element(by.id("hidePanelHeader"));

  this.checkHidePanelHeaderCb = () => {
    this.hidePanelHeaderCb.isSelected().then(selected => {
      if(!selected) {
        this.hidePanelHeaderCb.click();
      }
    });
  };
};
module.exports = PageObject;
```

I would suggest reading [fat arrow syntax and lexical scoping](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/#functionality-lexical-scoping-this).